# `go build` versus `go build file.go`

Tags: go, cgo

I am having trouble building a very simple go program that calls c code via cgo.
My setup:

```
$: echo $GOPATH
/go
$: pwd
/go/src/main
$: ls
ctest.c  ctest.h  test.go
```

test.go contains:
package main

```
// #include "ctest.c"
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func main() {
  cs := C.ctest(C.CString("c function"))
  defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
  index := "hello from go: " + C.GoString(cs)
  fmt.Println(index)
}
```

ctest.h contains:

```
char* ctest (char*);
```

ctest.c contains:

```
#include "ctest.h"

char* ctest (char* input) {
  return input;
};
```

When I run `go build test.go` I get a binary, `test` that I can run which prints the expected `hello from go: c function`

However when I run `go build` I get the error:

```
# main
/tmp/go-build599750908/main/_obj/ctest.o: In function `ctest':
./ctest.c:3: multiple definition of `ctest'
/tmp/go-build599750908/main/_obj/test.cgo2.o:/go/src/main/ctest.c:3: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is happening with `go build` that is not in `go build test.go` that is causing the error?

Comment: Bonus, because I am a c n00b:
It seems like most people are only including a `.h` file in the `#include` prior to `import`ing `"C"`.
When I try to import `ctest.h` instead of `ctest.c`, then run `go build test.go` I get the error:
`# command-line-arguments /tmp/go-build816364105/command-line-arguments/_obj/test.cgo2.o: In  function '_cgo_d004500c1b08_Cfunc_ctest': ./test.go:39: undefined reference to 'ctest' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Is there some configuration I need to set so that it pairs the `.c` file with the `.h` file in the `#include`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your code carefully. Read the error message. Correct your error:

```
// #include "ctest.h"
```

`test.go`:

```
package main

// #include "ctest.h"
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"
import "fmt"

func main() {
  cs := C.ctest(C.CString("c function"))
  defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
  index := "hello from go: " + C.GoString(cs)
  fmt.Println(index)
}
```

`ctest.h`:

```
char* ctest (char*);
```

`ctest.c`:

```
#include "ctest.h"

char* ctest (char* input) {
  return input;
};
```

Output:

```
$ rm ./test
$ ls
ctest.c  ctest.h  test.go
$ go build
$ ls
ctest.c  ctest.h  test  test.go
$ ./test
hello from go: c function
$
```

Comment: Wow... I could have sworn that I had already tried `// #include "ctest.h"` to include the `ctest` function. But this is definitely working as you describe for me.